# Convert ASCII strings to Hex strings in Python

Tags: python

How can I convert ASCII strings to Hex strings in Python ? Is there any built in function I can use for this ?

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess a web search was not an option? https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=python+ascii+to+hex&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you mean by "ASCII to hex", but you should be able to adapt this approach to get whatever you're looking for:

```
>>> foo = "foo"
>>> ''.join(hex(ord(c))[2:] for c in foo)
'666f6f'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Sam! This is exactly what I was looking for.